# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape' error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

Hello i am currently getting this error, when i try to test the CNN model.

```
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
CATEGORIES = ["cats","dogs"]
def prepare(file):
    IMG_SIZE = 50
    img_array = cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    return new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("CNN.model")
image = "datasets/test_set/dogs/dog.4001.jpg" 
prediction = model.predict([image])
prediction = list(prediction[0])
print(CATEGORIES[prediction.index(max(prediction))])
```

When I run the code I get the error:

```
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 265, in standardize_single_array
    if (x.shape is not None and len(x.shape) == 1 and

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Anyone who can tell me my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call `prepare`... So, your `image` variable should look like this:

```
image = prepare("datasets/test_set/dogs/dog.4001.jpg")
```

Comment: Thanks man! but now I get a different error:
error: OpenCV(4.1.1) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:3720: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'

Comment: Do you know what it means?

Comment: make sure this image is in the right location... I suggest passing the absolute path

Comment: maybe your file doesn't exist and you input None into cv2.resize

Comment: Thanks! I mistyped the path and added an extra s on the dataset folder hehe